# Does javascript not have bracket notation slicing? I.e. string[0:4]

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find an answer to this, searched 'bracket notation string' but could not find anything. Say I have:

```
let s = 'apple'
```

I know I can access any letter with `s[x]` but can you slice a string this way using javascript. I.e

```
s[0:3]
```

to return `"appl"`?

Comment: do `s.slice(0, 4)` to get `appl`

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-slice-notation

Comment: @cartant thanks for including this

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to obtain slices from an array:

```
let s = 'apple'

let mySlice = s.slice(0,4)
console.log(mySlice) // appl
```

Comment: Correct. From Mozilla: "The original array will not be modified."

Comment: Keep in mind that it returns a shallow copy of the original array. For object references, `slice` just copies the references to the new array. You're still safe when dealing with strings. From the docs linked in my answer:  For strings, numbers and booleans (not `String`, `Number` and `Boolean` objects), `slice` copies the values into the new array. Changes to the string, number, or boolean in one array do not affect the other array.